# Some SQL Server 2016 columns fail to attach to Access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am attaching from MS Access 2017 to the new World Wide importers sample database for SQL Server, if I attach the `Cities` table, I only get 8 the 13 columns in the table to show up in Access. The missing columns are:

```
Country, Continent, Sales Territory, Subregion, Location, Lineage Key
```

Can anyone tell me why the table attaches, but these columns are not part of the attachment?

Comment: What are the datatypes for the missing columns on the source? Might be that the source and destination columns' datatypes do not match (or a conversion isn't possible ) and hence the issue.

Comment: they are nvarchars and ints...nothing there to explain it

Comment: I tried linking to another sample table...all the fields linked fine

Comment: My `Cities` table has only 8 columns.